# Android Nexus Test Runs Successfully from .NET but fails when ran from UFT

Tags: c#, android, .net, appium, hp-uft

My real device android nexus test runs successfully from .net but when I call the same function from UFT it fails with an :Invalid locator strategy:Css selector error.

I am using:
 Windows machine
 appium 1.4.0
 VS .net 2013 - C# 
 UFT 11.53 .net Add-in
 Nexus 5 - Android M 
 Selenium Webdriver 2.42

My test launches chrome then clicks on a link which then opens my test application. (I have to switch to Native_View context).

When ran from .net, this test works fine. But when I run the same function from UFT (creating an instance of the .net object) - then I get :Invalid locator strategy:Css selector. Any assistance would be appreciated.

UFT code:

```
 Set objTest = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("MyAndroidTest.MyAndroidTestClass","C:\automation\API\MyAndroidTest.dll")
 results = objTest.MyEnrollment("name","password")
```

.Net code:

```
public string MyEnrollment(string name, string password)
{
    base.driver.SetContext(contextNames[0]);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    var btnActivate = base.driver.FindElementByName("Activate");
    if (btnActivate == null)
          result = false;               
    else
    {
       btnActivate.Click();
       result = true;
    }
   ...............
   ...............
   return result;
}
```

This is my log file from appium:

```
 info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client:     {"cmd":"action","action":"getDataDir","params":{}}
    info: [debug] dataDir set to: /data/local/tmp
    info: Killing any old chromedrivers, running: FOR /F "usebackq tokens=5" %a in (
`netstat -nao ^| findstr /R /C:"9515 "`) do (FOR /F "usebackq" %b in (`TASKLIST
/FI "PID eq %a" ^| findstr /I chromedriver.exe`) do (IF NOT %b=="" TASKKILL /F /
PID %a))
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getDataDir
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"\/data\
/local\/tmp"}
info: No old chromedrivers seemed to exist
info: Spawning chromedriver with: C:\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\chromedriv
er\windows\chromedriver.exe --url-base=wd/hub --port=9515
info: [CHROMEDRIVER STDOUT] Starting ChromeDriver 2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec179
7c81ea9a20326839860b7d3) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
info: Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/status] with n
o body
info: Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"","status":0,"value":{"build":
{"version":"alpha"},"os":{"arch":"x86_64","name":"Windows NT","version":"6.1 SP1
"}}}
info: Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/session] wi
th body: {"desiredCapabilities":{"chromeOptions":{"androidPackage":"com.android.
chrome","androidDeviceSerial":"08d257330222a227"}}}
info: Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"f5ce7ed1b154d5ac6ec8b21724f707
47","status":0,"value":{"acceptSslCerts":true,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"b
rowserConnectionEnabled":false,"browserName":"chrome","chrome":{},"cssSelect...
info: [debug] Overriding session id with "f5ce7ed1b154d5ac6ec8b21724f70747"
info: [debug] Device launched! Ready for commands
info: [debug] Setting command timeout to the default of 60 secs
info: [debug] Appium session started with sessionId f5ce7ed1b154d5ac6ec8b21724f7
0747
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 303 8913.062 ms - 70
info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/f5ce7ed1b154d5ac6ec8b21724f70747 {}
info: Proxying [GET /wd/hub/session/f5ce7ed1b154d5ac6ec8b21724f70747] to [GET ht
tp://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/session/f5ce7ed1b154d5ac6ec8b21724f70747] with body:
{}
info: Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"f5ce7ed1b154d5ac6ec8b21724f707
47","status":0,"value":{"acceptSslCerts":true,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"b
rowserConnectionEnabled":false,"browserName":"chrome","chrome":{},"cssSelect...
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/f5ce7ed1b154d5ac6ec8b21724f70747 200 7.688 ms - 50
6
info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/f5ce7ed1b154d5ac6ec8b21724f70747/contexts {}
info: Available contexts: NATIVE_APP,WEBVIEW_1
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":["NATIVE_AP
P","WEBVIEW_1"],"sessionId":"f5ce7ed1b154d5ac6ec8b21724f70747"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/f5ce7ed1b154d5ac6ec8b21724f70747/contexts 200 6.78
1 ms - 94 {"status":0,"value":["NATIVE_APP","WEBVIEW_1"],"sessionId":"f5ce7ed1b1
54d5ac6ec8b21724f70747"}
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/f5ce7ed1b154d5ac6ec8b21724f70747/context {"name":
"NATIVE_APP"}
info: Available contexts: NATIVE_APP,WEBVIEW_1
info: Set mode: Proxying to Appium Bootstrap
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":null,"sessi
onId":"f5ce7ed1b154d5ac6ec8b21724f70747"}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/f5ce7ed1b154d5ac6ec8b21724f70747/context 200 12.4
95 ms - 72 {"status":0,"value":null,"sessionId":"f5ce7ed1b154d5ac6ec8b21724f7074
7"}
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/f5ce7ed1b154d5ac6ec8b21724f70747/element {"using"
:"css selector","value":"*[name=\"Activate\"]","locator":"css selector"}
info: [debug] Invalid locator strategy: css selector
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":9,"value":{"message":"I
nvalid locator strategy: css selector","origValue":"Invalid locator strategy: cs
s selector"},"sessionId":"f5ce7ed1b154d5ac6ec8b21724f70747"}
```

I did research Invalid locator strategy: css selector”...looking at selenium version compatability with the version of appium that I am using...other than this...no other leads while researching.

Comment: downloaded the latest selenium version and changed my references in .net to point to latest WebDriver dlls...started getting can not start new session errors..so immediately switched back to working version. Now when I run the test from .net I am receiving the same error that I was getting from UFT.

Comment: found the following link..there was a bug in selenium but correction in version 2.47 : https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/f5b5a92559762d2ef32ebe85322c50fe66a271a3?diff=split

Comment: Steps I took to finally resolve my issue:  1. In .Net went to References >> Manage NuGet Packages...Searched on webdriver >> upgraded to latest versions of selenium webdriver and support class >> upgraded Appium webdriver to latest version 1.4.0.3

Comment: 2. Updated code --- added package using  `OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Android;` updated code:  `public AppiumDriver<AppiumWebElement> driver;    driver = new AndroidDriver<AppiumWebElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);`